# Why value is not passed on?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the basics of JS. Why the following script produces always the same answer. Why user choice is not passed to the function? Please give answer using only plain JS.

```
<script>
    document.writeln('First person:');
</script>

<select id="monthSelect1">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<select id="daySelect1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<br />

<script>
    document.writeln('Second person:');
</script>

<select id="monthSelect2">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<select id="daySelect2">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<br />

<input type="button" value="Calculate!" onclick=showResult()>

<script>

    var e = document.getElementById('monthSelect1');
    var i = e.selectedIndex;
    var sMonth1 = e.options[i].value;

    var e = document.getElementById('daySelect1');
    var i = e.selectedIndex;
    var sDay1 = e.options[i].value;

    var e = document.getElementById('monthSelect2');
    var i = e.selectedIndex;
    var sMonth2 = e.options[i].value;

    var e = document.getElementById('daySelect2');
    var i = e.selectedIndex;
    var sDay2 = e.options[i].value;

    function showResult()
    {
        alert('First person: ' + sMonth1 + '/' +  sDay1 + 
        ' Second person: ' + sMonth2 + '/' + sDay2);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate the values inside the showResult function. The script runs when the page loads and all values are fetched and stored in the variables.

Inside your showrresult function you are just calling that variables which contains the past values. that's why same result is shown always.

Also note you are re-declaring same variables `e and i` again and again. Instead just the first statement must contain `var` while the other statements can avoid it.

```
function showResult()
{
    var e = document.getElementById('monthSelect1');
    var i = e.selectedIndex;
    var sMonth1 = e.options[i].value;

    e = document.getElementById('daySelect1');
    i = e.selectedIndex;
    var sDay1 = e.options[i].value;

    e = document.getElementById('monthSelect2');
    i = e.selectedIndex;
    var sMonth2 = e.options[i].value;

    e = document.getElementById('daySelect2');
    i = e.selectedIndex;
    var sDay2 = e.options[i].value;
    alert('First person: ' + sMonth1 + '/' +  sDay1 + 
    ' Second person: ' + sMonth2 + '/' + sDay2);
}
```

Comment: You should explain the reason why.

Answer (score 0):

Because you suffer from premature calculation.

What happens is this:

- You write "First person" (and why it's `document.write` and not a normal tag, a mystery)
- You create dropdowns
- You write "Second person"
- You create dropdowns
- You take the dropdown values and calculate result
- When a button is clicked, you show the calculated result

The calculation would need to be inside the function for it to recalculate it on each button click.

Answer (score 0):

@maxval the problem you are facing is because you are delaring the variables outside the function.so inside the function the value of variable will be **undefined**.So the control never reaches your declaration part. The correct code should be

```
<div>
    <select id="ddl1">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="click" onclick="getdata();" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getdata()
    {
    var obj=document.getElementById('ddl1');
    var val=obj.value;
    alert('value:'+val);
    }
    </script>
```

you can easily debug your javascript using **Mozilla Firefox add on- firebug** or if you are using **IDE** like **visual studio** you can debug javascript using **internet explorer**

Comment: I understand. It is the problem with global and local variables.